# Flexbox fill remaining height of 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why doesn't "Box 2" fill the full (available) space? The height:100% is ignored...

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box1">Box 1</div>
    <div id="box2">Box 2</div>
    <div id="box3">Box 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #cccccc;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

#box1 {
  background: red;
  height: 50px
}

#box2 {
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1
}

#box3 {
  background: green;
  height: 50px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/618axkjy/2/

Thanks!

Comment: Use percentages (%), not pixels (px)

Answer (score 8):

It's because the parent `#container` element doesn't have a height of `100%`. At the moment, the height of the `body` element is determined by the height of the `#container` element (since it's the only child). Since you're defining the height of the `#container` element using percentages, the height will remain the same since the parent's height is also the same.

You need to set the `height` of the `html`/`body` elements to `100%`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ed5t64dd/)

```
html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

..or you could define the height of the `#container` element in [viewport-percentage units, `vh`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths):

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/f60tLhf4/)

```
#container {
    height: 100vh;    /* 100% of the viewport height */
}
```